# Monitor data sent to cloud in event hub and process it using event hub?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have machinery that is sending csv files into the cloud. I am not too clear where these files go at the moment but assuming the data goes into a specific place is there anyway to have an event hub automatically pick up new csv files and process them?

I am looking at my event hub being the input for a stream analytics job which will pass the data to power bi

I already know how to do the steam analysis side it’s having an event hub pick up the files I am not sure of

Or do I need to spin up a virtual machine that monitors and then sends data?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit vague; you need to find out where your files go to...

You could use something like Logic App or Function App to be triggered when a new `csv` file is uploaded, then parse it and send sent to Event Hub. Both Logic and Function apps have connections to both files and event hubs; Functions are more code-oriented, Logic is visual workflow based.

Comment: Ok thanks! My user is being a bit vague too! All I know at the Moment is that files are sent to the cloud that’s it lol